# Espresso - Check if the screen is Visible or not

Tags: android, android-espresso, android-testing

I'm trying to write some tests with the new android-test-kit (Espresso). But I can't find any information on how to check if a view is displayed and perform some actions on it (like clicking buttons, e.t.c.). Note that the view I need to check if it exists or not. If it does perform action on the view and if not proceed to the next view.

Any help would be appreciated. I just need a link, or some example code for the basics:

Check if the view exists
If yes,Perform action
If not, proceed to next screen

Answer (score 2):

You can use a classic option "try/catch":

```
try {
    onView(withText("Text")).check(matches(isDisplayed()));
    //perform some actions on this view
} catch (NoMatchingViewException notExist) {
    //proceed to the next screen
}
```

Comment: Works, although I had to catch `Throwable` instead of `NoMatchingViewException` (Espresso `3.4.0`)

Answer (score 2):

```
Object currentActivity;

@Nullable
private Activity getCurrentActivity() throws Throwable {
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            Collection resumedActivities = ActivityLifecycleMonitorRegistry.getInstance().getActivitiesInStage(RESUMED);
            if (resumedActivities.iterator().hasNext()) {
                currentActivity = resumedActivities.iterator().next();
            }
        }
    });

    return (Activity) currentActivity;
}
```

with this, you can get the Activity that is currently displayed. After that by doing something like this, you can make a safe code section

```
HOMESCREEN:
        {
            for (; ; ) {
                if (getCurrentActivity() != null) {
                    //check if it is the required screen
                    if (getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName().toLowerCase().contains("homescreen")) {
                        //if it is the required screen, break the 
                        //loop and continue execution
                         break HOMESCREEN;
                    }  else {
                        //wait for 2 seconds and run the loop again
                        sleep(2000);
                    }
                } else {
                    break HOMESCREEN;
                }
            }
        }
```

*sleep(2000)* is a custom function which just calls thread.sleep like shown below:

```
private void sleep(long milliseconds) {
    try {
        Thread.sleep(millis);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException("Cannot execute Thread.sleep()");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You must control the behavior of your test. So, you must have to add some preconditions, or create the @Rule that will control the behavior, for example by adding parameters depending on which your view will be displayed or not.